# Flowtype: Unsafe instance variable access

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype, es6-class

```
/* @flow */

class Foo {
    blah: string;
    bar: string;
    constructor(blah: string, bar?: string) {
            this.blah = blah
            if (bar) {
                this.bar = bar
            }
    }
}

const foo = new Foo('okok')
foo.bar
```

https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsAMTjjAG9UBIAI2wCcAuMXAFzoEsA7AcwG5UAvugxxOrMFBJgAvGE4BTJMTgAKAJSpJcAHS06QA

What does this not throw a flowtype error?

**Edit:**

This potentially answers my question...

https://flowtype.org/docs/nullable-types.html#undefined-values-and-optional-types

> Undefined Values and Optional Types Undefined values, just like null,
>   can cause issues too. Unfortunately, undefined values are ubiquitous
>   in JavaScript and it is hard to avoid them without severely affecting
>   the usability of the language. For example, arrays can have holes for
>   elements; object properties can be dynamically added and removed. Flow
>   ignores the possibility of undefined resulting from object property
>   and array element accesses. Being stricter would force the programmer
>   to do undefined checks (like null checks) on each dereference of an
>   array element or object property to get anything useful done.
>
> However, Flow does detect undefined local variables and return values,
>   and it considers optional parameters and properties to possibly be
>   undefined. As such, uses of these types must be guarded by undefined
>   checks to avoid errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (v0.36) class fields are not ensured by Flow

```
class Foo {
  bar: string;
}

new Foo().bar // no error
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that flow correctly catches these errors as of `0.47` (and presumably for some earlier versions).

As a caveat, if you extend a class that flow does not understand, it will not catch these errors.

```
// @flow
import Model from './Model'; // a non-flown file
class A extends Model {}
const a = new A();
a.bar; // will not fail, because Model might have a bar field.
```